# c# asp.net table row always going in the same row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TblPrikaz.BorderWidth = 1;

    XmlDocument baza = new XmlDocument();
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("baza.xml"));
    baza.Load(reader);
    TableRow line = new TableRow();
    TableCell id = new TableCell();
    TableCell ime = new TableCell();
    TableCell prezime = new TableCell();
    TableCell godiste = new TableCell();

    id.Text = "ID";
    ime.Text = "Ime";
    prezime.Text = "Prezime";
    godiste.Text = "Godiste";

    line.BackColor = Color.Green;

    line.Cells.Add(id);
    line.Cells.Add(ime);
    line.Cells.Add(prezime);
    line.Cells.Add(godiste);

    TblPrikaz.Rows.Add(line);


    XmlNodeList popis = baza.GetElementsByTagName("element");

    for (int i = 0; i < popis.Count; i++)
    {

    if (string.Compare(popis[i].Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString(), "0") == 0) continue;

    id.Text = popis[i].Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString();
    ime.Text = popis[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
    prezime.Text = popis[i].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
    godiste.Text = popis[i].ChildNodes[2].InnerText;

    line.Cells.Add(id);
    line.Cells.Add(ime);
    line.Cells.Add(prezime);
    line.Cells.Add(godiste);

    TblPrikaz.Rows[i].Cells.Add(id);
    TblPrikaz.Rows[i].Cells.Add(ime);
    TblPrikaz.Rows[i].Cells.Add(prezime);
    TblPrikaz.Rows[i].Cells.Add(godiste);
    }
}
```

for some reason, the table only shows the loast row read fromthe document and I have no idea why it is doing that.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table always use the same row and cell objects, you need to create new ones in the loop:

id = new TableCell(); 
etc....

Answer (score 5):

You are not creating a new row on each iteration. Instead, you are updating the existing row.

```
XmlNodeList popis = baza.GetElementsByTagName( "element" );
for ( int i = 0; i < popis.Count; i++ )
{
    var element = popis[i];
    if ( element == null || element.Attributes == null )
        continue;

    if ( element.Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString() == "0" )
        continue;

    var idCell = new TableCell { Text = element.Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString() };
    var imeCell = new TableCell { Text = element.ChildNodes[0].InnerText };
    var prezimeCell = new TableCell { Text = element.ChildNodes[1].InnerText };
    var godisteCell = new TableCell { Text = element.ChildNodes[2].InnerText };

    var row = new TableRow();
    row.Cells.Add( idCell );
    row.Cells.Add( imeCell );
    row.Cells.Add( prezimeCell );
    row.Cells.Add( godisteCell );

    TblPrikaz.Rows.Add( row );
}
```